# App SDK: Query data over a workspace/multiple projects

Tags: rally

I'm creating a report that needs to obtain data from a workspace that has several projects in it. Is there a way to specify to either search a whole workspace or multiple projects when creating the RallyDataSource? Creating a data source per project doesn't sound like the best way of going about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your projects have one common parent you can specify the parent project and projectScopeDown true:

```
var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('/workspace/12345',
    '/project/23456', false, true);
```

Otherwise in your queryConfig you can set the project to null to query the entire workspace:

```
rallyDataSource.findAll({
    key: 'stories',
    project: null,
    type: 'hierarchicalrequirement',
}, callback, errorCallback);
```

You could further filter it to specific projects like so:

```
rallyDataSource.findAll({
    key: 'stories',
    project: null,
    type: 'hierarchicalrequirement',
    query: '((Project = /project/23456) OR (Project = /project/34567))'
}, callback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: Thanks, setting project to null achieved what I wanted.