# Rally SDK: Pulling in Data From all Projects in Workspace

Tags: javascript, sdk, rally

I'm creating an app that adds up user story data per feature but noticed when a specific project is selected user stories from other projects aren't loaded in the store.

> I'd like to pull in data from all projects in the Workspace in SDK 2.1.

This question was answered here: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903864/app-sdk-query-data-over-a-workspace-multiple-projects), but this is from a previous version of the SDK. I'm wondering if there is an equivalent solution in version 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common enough use case that we probably should have included an example in the docs: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/data_stores-section-scoping

Anyway, you can use the same project: null trick.  Just make sure you also specify the workspace:

```
context: {
    workspace: this.getContext().getWorkspaceRef(),
    project: null
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!